# Web Page with User Info

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a (ASP)web page where the logged in user(customer) can change their contact info. i.e essentially the page will display one user at a time from the SQL DB.
I initially designed the web Page with textboxes & used HTML tables for formatting.
Now user has added multiple phone numbers (0-8 types). Maybe email addresses will be several too.
The phone nos / Email IDs will be stored in separate tables, so really there is no limit on how many phone numbers each customer can have.

I am wondering if I should use the textboxes for the address part & use dropdownlists for phone nos & email addresses. Also the HTML tables are becoming unmanageable as client wants to use the page to show some other information too. VS2008 keeps adding styles although I am using CSS

Alternatively, I can use a Detail view /Forms View.

What will be a good design to display the user info?

Answer (score 0):

Usability is indeed a tough thing to make all users comfortable with, and the more information they have to add, the more use there is for proper setups.

I'm a bit curious about what type of site this is? Most of the sites I've helped develop over the years where users should be able to add multiple email adresses was mostly social networks where they had personal email, yahoo, msn etc. If it is this type of information, then make a textbox for each of these type of special emails. Same goes for phone nummbers -- it's been a lot of personal phoneno, work related phone, direct landline, cellphone etc. It all really depends on what type of site these user profiles are on.

If it's corporate userprofiles where they have to add clientell emails, it might be a good idea with a dropdownlist or even better, a gridview where you can edit the rows since you develop in `ASP.NET`.

Hope this helped give you an idea on how to handle the informations on the userprofiles :)

Comment: It is a business website. This is to help offload the database entry work from the admin to the customer. Adding mutiple phone nos & email IDs was due to the fact the user-customer will be mostly on the road.